# Is it possible to create a template which, when specialized, yields another template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working with some unfortunate code that has two completely different serialization mechanisms. One uses a template for the archive that looks like `template <class Archive> void serialize_v1(Archive& a)`, while the other uses `template <template <bool> class Archive> void serialize_v2(Archive<false>& a)`. The first overloads an operator to serialize like `a % foo` to serialize, while the second uses methods on the archive like `a.proc_int(foo)`.

I'm trying to write an adapter between the two so I don't have to write two serialization functions all the time. Ideally I'd have something like:

```
template <class ArchiveV1>
class serialize_adapter
{
    serialize_adapter(ArchiveV1& one) : one(one) { }; 

    // functions for v2 serialization
    void proc_int(int x) {
        one % x;
    }

    ArchiveV1& one;
}

template <class ArchiveV1>
void serialize_v1(ArchiveV1& one)
{
    serialize_v2(serialize_adapter(one)); // calls adapter's v2 funcs
}
```

However, `serialize_v2` takes a `template <bool> class ArchiveV2`, which `serialize_adapter(one)` does not match - since it is just a `class ArchiveV1`. But `serialize_adapter` can't just take a `bool` - it does have to take the `ArchiveV1` parameter.

It seems like I need to create a template which specializes on the `Archive` type, which results in a template that specializes on the `bool` that I can then pass to `serialize_v2`. How can I go about doing that, or what's the right approach if that's the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template <bool> class ArchiveV2` can be seen as a metafunction `S: bool -> type`. What you need can be seen as a metafunction `A: type -> S`, that is, a "metametafunction". A metafunction that returns a metafunction can be written via a member template:

```
template<class ArchiveV1>
struct serialize_adapter
{
    template<bool>
    struct result
    {
        void proc_int(int x) {
            one % x;
        }

        ArchiveV1& one;
    };
};
```

Note the analogy to "ordinary" metafunctions:

```
template<class X>
struct metafun
{
    using result = /* some type */;
};
```

(`result` is often called `type`)

The adapter function can then be written as:

```
template <class ArchiveV1>
void serialize_v1(ArchiveV1& one)
{
    using adapter = serialize_adapter<ArchiveV1>::template result<false>;
    serialize_v2(adapter{one}); // calls adapter's v2 funcs
}
```

Comment: If you need more of these adapter classes, you could also introduce a dummy bool via inheritance + CRTP.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way round: write a `serialize_adaptor` which takes the more more specialized type -- that is the class which stems from a template with a boolean parameter -- and turns that into the general one.

Example:

```
template <template<bool> class ArchiveV2>
class serialize_adapter
{
    serialize_adapter(ArchiveV2<false>& one) : one(one) { }; 

    // functions for v1 serialization
    void operator%(int x) {
        one.proc_int(x);
    }

    ArchiveV2<false>& one;
}

template <template<typename> class ArchiveV2>
void serialize_v2(ArchiveV2<false>& one)
{
    serialize_v1(serialize_adapter(one)); // calls adapter's v1 funcs
}
```

Here, you should probably add some further specializations for the case when the boolean parameter is `true`.